# openbsd pf : how to allow/pass out smtp traffic?

Tags: email, smtp, firewall, relay, openbsd

OpenBsd 6.2 - pf

I'm trying to set up an `smtp` relay to `gmail`.

since my connections are ok, i thought "ok... add `smtp`"... Bin non ! :/

Everything works fine if I empty `/etc/pf.conf` (so `gmail` connector is ok, `/etc/mail/smtpd.conf` and `secrets.db` too).

```
# OpenBSD 6.2 : pf.conf,v 1.54 

int_if = "alc0"

tcp_ok = "{domain,ssh,smtp,auth,ntp,https,mysql}"
udp_ok = "{domain,ntp}"

set skip on lo

block all

pass proto tcp to any port $tcp_ok keep state
pass proto udp to any port $udp_ok keep state
```

Can't figure out what is wrong adding `smtp` port knowing that everything is ok without this service.

Thanks.

Comment: euh... of course you should read "Hi..." on first line... Ok Done... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...

Re-examining the logs `/var/log/maillog` I saw :

```
[...]mta event=connecting address=tls://108.177.15.16:587
```

So

```
grep -w 587 /etc/services
```

to get...

```
submission 587/tcp ... # mail message submission
submission 587/udp ... # mail message submission
```

Updated :

```
tcp_ok = "{domain,ssh,smtp,submission,auth,ntp,https,mysql}"
udp_ok = "{domain,ntp,submission}"
```

Reloaded `pf` rules :

```
pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```

Ok... :D